# New installation with invalid signatures: NODATA 1 NODATA 2 error

Tags: upgrade, updates

I am installing 13.04 into a VirtualBox machine.

After installing, I receive this error after `sudo apt-get update`:

```
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com raring Release
E: Erro GPG: http://archive.ubuntu.com raring Release: the following signatures were invalid: NODATA 1 NODATA 2
```

I have already tried:

1. Install minimal server version;
2. Install 12.04 desktop version;

Everything gives me the same error.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ubuntu 12.04 GPG error: http://archive.ubuntu.com precise Release: The following signatures were invalid: NODATA 1 NODATA 2](http://askubuntu.com/questions/470699/ubuntu-12-04-gpg-error-http-archive-ubuntu-com-precise-release-the-following)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Got NODATA issue: 'NODATA' (does the network require authentication?)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/474549/got-nodata-issue-nodata-does-the-network-require-authentication)

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest reverting to other country's server instead of the main archive.ubuntu.com, which is probably throttled:

[image: Choose server udate]