# Ubuntu 12.04 GPG error: http://archive.ubuntu.com precise Release: The following signatures were invalid: NODATA 1 NODATA 2

Tags: apt, updates, authentication, gnupg

I know this is asked often but nothing seems to work for me.
Every time I try to update I get the following:

```
sudo apt-get update
Get:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise Release.gpg
Get:2 http://ppa.launchpad.net precise Release.gpg
Get:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com precise Release                            
Get:4 http://ppa.launchpad.net precise Release.gpg                         
Get:5 http://ppa.launchpad.net precise Release                              
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com precise Release                               
E: GPG error: http://archive.ubuntu.com precise Release: The following signatures were invalid: NODATA 1 NODATA 2
```

The only way I can successfully execute

```
sudo apt-get update
```

is by removing ALL software sources (which is pointless).

Regardless of whatever software source I use (official ubuntu or some other PPA) I get the same errors.

**So far I have tried:**

1. Changing the server from MAIN to some other . . . no joy
2. The suggested fixes from [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2202787), [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PackageManagerTroubleshootingProcedure), [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/445905/the-following-signatures-were-invalid-nodata-1-nodata-2), and [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/104213/gpg-invalid-signature).

Nothing seems to work. It seems that all my key data is missing and I can't figure out how to get it back.

Any help would be very appreciated !

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion 123456 but as I said I have tried changing the server with no joy.

Answer (score 3):

Okay, some may say this was a stupid error on my part but I'm noting this here for anyone who may get similar issues.

If trying the solutions in the links I provided above did not work for you then chances are your system is behind a proxy.

I accidentally put my system behind a proxy when using a particular network extender [this one if you curious](http://www.netgear.com/home/products/networking/wifi-range-extenders/WN1000RP.aspx).

When your system is put behind a proxy and it is not configured to be that way you will get these strange GPG errors. So your choices are to reconfigure to work through a proxy or to get rid of the proxy (I chose the latter).

**NOTE**: A simple way to confirm that your system is behind a proxy is to **ping** a website and observe the IP or name of the **from** portion of the reply. If the from portion is from an unexpected address then you may be accidentally behind a proxy as I was.